# How do you make a Bitmap image point forward the entire time it's moving and turning?

Tags: java, android, geometry, trigonometry

Is there some sort of formula for rotating the arrow in [this link right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Npy.png) to make sure it's always pointing toward the red? Each time I've tried, I'd always get a number that's off, and the arrow's rotation is not in sync with the arrow's turning and movement.

A couple of snippets of code to show what I'm working with:

```
arrow.moveX(true);
arrow.moveY(true);

if(arrow.turning) {
     arrow.turn(player.direction / (0.75 * arrow.getSpeed()));
}
```

The arrow's speed is 12.5 units/time if that's important. As for the movement itself:

```
public void moveX(boolean turn) {

    if(turn) {
        x += speed * Math.cos(angle);
    } else {
        x += speed;
    }

}

public void moveY(boolean turn) {

    if(turn) {
        y += speed * Math.sin(angle);
    } else {
        y += speed;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to render the arrow's sprite make sure that the pointer itself is facing that "forward" direction that it's moving in, no matter how much it rotates. Here is the render method itself if that's necessary:

```
@Override
public void render(Canvas c, Paint p) {

    matrix.setTranslate((float)x, (float)y);

    if(alive) {
        matrix.postRotate(drawnAngle, (float) (x + width / 2), (float) (y + height / 2));
    } else {
        matrix.postRotate(angle, (float) (x + width / 2), (float) (y + height / 2));
        angle += speed * 2;
    }

    c.drawBitmap(getSprite(), matrix, p);

}
```

The variable `drawnAngle` has a value of 0 right now, it's a placeholder. It was just my attempt of trying to find the right number to rotate the arrow by.

Answer (score 1):

So I've actually spent hours trying to figure this out, and the moment I decide to post for help, I figured it out! It turns out that while I was using radians in the first snippet of code (the actual movement), I was supposed to be using degrees in the actual rotate in that last snippet!

I changed `drawnAngle` to `(float)(angle * (180 / Math.PI))` and this worked as a solution for me!

Hopefully no one else has this problem.